# Hadoop inverted index program error

Tags: hadoop

Can somebody tell me what does this error means? and how can I get the output?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myorg.LineIndexer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

This is the code I want to execute :

http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-excercise/source/browse/trunk/lineindexer/LineIndexer.java?spec=svn15&r=15

Answer (score 0):

Is the class included in your jar? Seems not to be the case.

So you have to include the class in the jar, you are passing while starting the job.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps and it worked.

PS: Please make sure you have a sample.txt file in the HDFS and LineIndexer.java in the current directory.

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-core.jar *.java
jar cvf li.jar *.class
hadoop jar ii.jar LineIndexer sample.txt li1
hadoop fs -cat li1/part-00000
```